# Use case diagram for web application

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm a student working in project which need to develop a web application (website / app mobile).
the main goal of this application is to allow consumer to rent / exchange parking in real time (Consumer to Consumer).

Edit : Hello, i will give more details about the project :
The project aims to bring a mobile application to market
which will allow:

- The exchange of car parks between individuals
- The real-time rental of a parking space

The exchange of car parks between individuals will take place after registration and validation of the
owners' information (such as email,...) and car parks (location, address,
latitude, longitude, height, surface, access,...)
As well as their times and availability dates...
A back end program will match the possible car parks for Exchange

A member of the app will be able to see in real time the available car parks in
depending on its GPS position and time slot
A request for permission can then be sent through the application to the
owner of the chosen car park.

I am working on my use case and I need some help and advice.

[image: use case diagramm]

Comment: And which help do you need?

Comment: I want to know if my use case is correct

Comment: How should anyone know by what you offered so far?

Comment: Hello, i updated first posts with more informations. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can say that UML diagrams have a predefined *syntax* (the UML standard) and a *content* that depends on your specific project.

The syntax of your diagram is correct: it uses the standard shapes and connectors. Good job! I would suggest to work a little more on the presentation, the style (for example, connect the lines to the shapes). Take a look here for inspiration, this is a great website: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html

On the correctness of the content we can not help you, since you have not shared enough details about your project. My personal opinion (just an opinion!) is that you should either go high-level or fully-detailed, no in-betweens. For example you put *add, edit* and *delete parking*, this makes me think you are detailing everythng, but at the same time there is no *remove parking advertisement* or *remove reservation* so this makes me think that these actions are not possible. If this is not the case, you might want to add them or use something more generic like "manage parking", "manage advertisements".

Comment: Hello, i updated first post with more information about the project. yes , a client can delete add , edit info parking and delete parking but can't remove advertisement or remove reservation because i want to keep history of advertisement and reservation. thanks

Comment: What he said. There's one more issue: Login is no use case ut a constraint related to several use cases. A Login does not add any value. So you have to  remove that bubble.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i need to edit other things ? thanks